# Can't exit recovery mode after intalling HD revolution 71.1

Tags: rom-flashing, root-access

I started with a HTC ONE m7 with HD Revolution 12 and Android 4.2.2.

Downloaded and installed Android_Revolution_HD-One_71.1.zip.  Install seems to go fine.  After installation it asks me to fix permissions.  Also wiped from TWRP before installation.

After installing and rebooting I can only get to TWRP v2.5.0.0 or the bootloader mode that shows:

***TAMPERED***
***UNLOCKED***
HBOOT-1.44.0000
RADIO-4A.14.3250.15
OPEN DSP-v26.120.274.0202
eMMC-BOOT
May 3 2013, 20:01:28-1

FASTBOOT USB:
Bootloader
Reboot
Reboot Bootloader
Power Down

or HBOOT:
Fastboot
Recovery
Factory Reset
Simlock
Image CRC
Show Barcode

What now?  Everything I try takes me to either the Recovery Screen or the TWRP. 
:?

Comment: Try updating TWRP to 2.6.3.3+

Comment: My PC's not seeing the phone as a drive so there's no way for me drop installation files on it?

Comment: Have you tried mounting as a storage device from within recovery?

Comment: Just tried the mounting options under TWRP---Cache (x -checked) and Data (x-checked) and System and USB-OTG (Both unchecked).  Still not seeing anything on the PC

Comment: Is there some sort of USB Fast boot I should be doing from the PC side?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jonny Wright.  I was able to instal 2.6.33 thanks to this youtube vid:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HWj_1KHbuY.  Reinstalled and booted up normally.  Now in setup up redoing apps and email.  Thanks!!

Comment: @ThomasBright Glad to read you were able solving your issue! Could you please answer your own question, describing the steps you've taken (and giving the Youtube link as a reference)? This would help other users with similar trouble to identify this issue as being solved, and directing them to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sure IzzY!   Per Johnny Wrights recommendation I was trying to update TWRP to 2.6.3.3.   Plug in the phone to the PC via USB and make sure the phone is in FASTBOOT USB mode from the bootloader menu.   I installed "Minimal ADB and Fastboot". Running that from the command line (cmd.exe) you type "fastboot flash recovery " then drag the file.  (watch the youtube video-it will make more sense).  I my case it was the 2.6.3 TWRP .img file.  That pushes the update to the phone.  I already had the HD 71.1 zip on the phone.  I installed that via the TWRP install and from there it booted up normally.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summing up the solution from the comments, as neither OP nor the "solution provider" posted an answer:</sup>

Per Johnny Wrights recommendation I was trying to update TWRP to 2.6.3.3:

- Plug in the phone to the PC via USB and make sure the phone is in FASTBOOT USB mode from the bootloader menu.
- On the PC, I installed "Minimal ADB and Fastboot". Running that from the command line (cmd.exe) you type `fastboot flash recovery` then drag the file. (watch the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HWj_1KHbuY) – it will make more sense). I my case it was the 2.6.3 TWRP `.img` file. That pushes the update to the phone.
- I already had the HD 71.1 zip on the phone. I installed that via the *TWRP install* and from there it booted up normally.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, removing TWRP and reinstalling it solved the issue:

1. install stock recovery to replace the installed TWRP
2. install TWRP again so it replaces the stock recovery

After that, my device booted up normally.